# Is fs.file-max and ulimit nofile in AWS ECS limited by the EC2's fs.file-max and nofile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, ulimit

I am attempting to run a few load tests on Nginx running on ECS and I have set the `ulimit` to a higher value (777001) via the task definition as mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-ulimit.html).

Inside the container, the `ulimit -Hn` command and `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` run inside the container will give the same value () as output.

On the EC2 in which the container (one of the EC2s in the auto-scaling cluster) is running, `ulimit -Hn` is given as 1024 and `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` is given as 777001.

When I am running the load, I am getting `too many open files` errors when the requests per second hit around 500. (CPU usage and memory usage seem of the ECS service seems to be fine around 25%).

While doing a bit of digging on this I found [this medium post](https://medium.com/@pahud/ulimit-of-nofile-in-amazon-ecs-optimized-ami-6790aedee582), which refers the `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file and the startup options given to the docker daemon. In my case, the `cat /etc/sysconfig/docker` output is as follows.

```
# The max number of open files for the daemon itself, and all
# running containers.  The default value of 1048576 mirrors the value
# used by the systemd service unit.
DAEMON_MAXFILES=1048576

# Additional startup options for the Docker daemon, for example:
# OPTIONS="--ip-forward=true --iptables=true"
# By default we limit the number of open files per container
OPTIONS="--default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096"

# How many seconds the sysvinit script waits for the pidfile to appear
# when starting the daemon.
DAEMON_PIDFILE_TIMEOUT=10
OPTIONS="${OPTIONS} --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G"
```

I would like any help in understanding the following.

1. Does the ulimit nofile value on EC2 restrict the ulimit nofile on ECS even when the ulimit nofile is set to a higher value via the ECS task definition?
2. Do the OPTIONS parameters given to docker daemon in `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file restrict the ulimit nofile on ECS even when the ulimit nofile is set to a higher value via the ECS task definition?

Comment: any update on this?